How to redirect request of private Azure Key Vault vault.azure.net domain to private dns zone or private ip configured in private endpoint?
I have a private dns zone for a key vault named privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net. Inside it, I added a record for a private endpoint that is connected to a key vault with public access disabled.
I also have a private dns resolver configured that connects to the on-prem environment that contains conditional forwarders.
When I try to nslookup the key_vault_name.privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net I get the private ip as configured, but when I try to do with the key_vault_name.vault.azure.net I get the public ip (but with the public name and the private dns zone record name).
When I try to access the secrets or keys in the key vault I get the following error in the portal or with terraform (when I try to add a secret for a resource during creation):
Public network access is disabled and request is not from a trusted service nor via an approved private link. 
It works when I add the public name (example: key_vault_name.vault.azure.net) with the private ip to my host file.
Other resources I can connect to them using the name configured in the private dns zones.
I'm afraid to add also the vault.azure.net to my on-prem dns servers because we have public key vaults already in use.
Is the correct way to do it is by using DNS forwarding ruleset and connecting it to an outbound endpoint of the DNS private resolver and a rule with a domain name of vault.azure.net. and the destination ip of our DNS private resolver or on-prem dns servers
Because the resources in the on-prem and VNet that integrated with the On-Prem environment are managed by me but by our network and security manager.
I just researched and read the documentation and tried to use ChatGPT to find some solution.
This seems to be the best one if it works because it should only affect the private key vaults that are connected to this specific VNet that is responsible for new hybrid environments we deploy.


How to redirect request of private Azure Key Vault vault.azure.net domain to private dns zone or private ip configured in private endpoint?

The reason for the DNS issue you are facing is that you have configured the forwarder with the wrong DNS forwarder privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net, but you need to configure the ruleset with the following values
To resolve the issue, you need to configure conditional forwarders for both vault.azure.net and vaultcore.azure.net on your on-premises DNS. Follow the MS Doc for more details.

Public DNS zone forwarders for key vault, refer the MS Doc for more details

Once you have configured the conditional forwarders, you do not need to add the entry in the host file on the local server for DNS resolution.
Reference: Integrate Key Vault with Azure Private Link
Validate that the private link connection works
